# Updating ImageViews within a TilePane with JavaFX (Simple Reference Problem?)

Tags: java, android, arrays, javafx, reference

Currently, I am trying to update the ImageViews within each Tile of a TilePane.

Variable at top of class available to all methods: `ImageView imgArray[] = new ImageView[20];`

Creating the original TilePane:

```
public TilePane createTilePane() {
    TilePane tile = new TilePane();
    tile.setPrefColumns(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tile.getChildren().add(this.createImageView("https://media.forgecdn.net/avatars/141/115/636539774401917932.jpeg", i));
    } //for
    return tile;
} //createTilePane()

public ImageView createImageView(String url, int x) {
    Image image = new Image(url);

    imgArray[x] = new ImageView();

    imgArray[x].setImage(image);
    imgArray[x].setFitWidth(100.0);
    imgArray[x].setFitHeight(100.0);
    imgArray[x].setImage(image);

    return imgArray[x];
} //createImageView()
```

The problem is whenever I want to change an image within the tilepane I can't. For example I want to be able to do: `this.createImageView("url", 2);` to change a Tile within the TilePane.

I can do that with no errors, but the image is not changing.

Any ideas?

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createImageView` does not update the scene. It simply creates a new `ImageView` and updates the array containing the data. You need to update the scene, if you want to change the display. The best way of doing this in this scenario is modifying the `image` property of the `ImageView`.

Note that I've rewritten your code a bit to reuse the `Image` instance. `createImageView` has been renamed to `setImage`, since this seems like a better name for what it's doing to me:

```
public TilePane createTilePane() {
    // reuse large object
    Image image = new Image("https://media.forgecdn.net/avatars/141/115/636539774401917932.jpeg");

    TilePane tile = new TilePane();
    tile.setPrefColumns(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = createImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);
        imgArray[i] = imageView;
        tile.getChildren().add(imageView);
    } //for
    return tile;
} //createTilePane()

private ImageView createImageView() {
    ImageView image = new ImageView();
    image.setFitWidth(100d);
    image.setFitHeight(100d);
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int index, String url) {
    ImageView imageView = imgArray[index];
    Image image = new Image(url);

    // change image in ImageView that was added to the scene
    imageView.setImage(image);
}
```